# I already have PHP installed, what's the easiest (best) way to get GDLib installed?

Tags: php, macos, gd

I'm running a Mac Mini with Apache/PHP5/MySQL as my staging server.
I'm building and using software that requires GDLib for manipulating graphics.

How can I install this on my machine?
Im not much of a CI guru but Im not scared of it. I just have no clue how to troubleshoot errors or problems when ./configure says file not installed at the end or something.

Any help on this would be fantastic!
Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can upgrade to Snow Leopard it's included out of the box. Otherwise, the instructions [here](http://akrabat.com/2009/03/05/setting-up-php-on-os-x-leopard/) should help.

Comment: I think I'll just do this. Thanks didn't realize it was on SL

Answer (score 3):

Install [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/), you can set it to run on port :80 and you can still edit your config so www.example.site works just fine. I also have mine set so all of the files are still kept inside the /Sites/ folder.

Fixing the Apache/MySQL/PHP setup that comes bundles with OS X is very painful for non sysadmins, esp if you just want to get on with building sites.

Answer (score 0):

Normally gd is included by default. Check `phpinfo()`, if there is any gd mentioned then it is installed.

Comment: I know PHP5 comes with it by default, but not on Leopard for some reason.

Comment: However if the user does not compile GD into the PHP setup, it is not setup by 'default' ;)